# Replace ECS tasks in cluster using AWS cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to replace the current tasks in an ECS cluster.

Context:
I have 2 tasks (and a maximum of 4)
Every time I make a change to the docker image, the image is built, tagged, and pushed to ECR (through Jenkins). I wanted to add a timer and after x minutes, replace the current tasks with new ones (also in the CI/CD)

I tried

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster myCluster --service myService --task-definition myTaskDef
```

but it didn't work.

Also, several suggestions that I found in StackOverflow and forums, but in the best cases, I ended with 4 tasks, while, I just want to replace the current ones with new ones.

Is this possible using the CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would use `--force-new-deployment` parameter of [update-service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html):

> Whether to force a new deployment of the service. **Deployments are not forced by default**. You can use this option to trigger a new deployment with no service definition changes. For example, you can update a service's tasks to **use a newer Docker image** with the same image/tag combination (my_image:latest ) or to roll Fargate tasks onto a newer platform version.

Comment: Thanks, @Marcin I did also try that but I always end with 4 tasks instead of a replacement.

Comment: @Peter If you set desire capacity of your service to 4, you will always have 4 tasks.

Comment: Thanks as always, @Marcin 
It still doesn’t work.
My service has 2 desired count, min health of 50 and max health of 100. The deployment controller is ECS. So, I have 2 tasks running in the cluster. I push a new image to ECR with the latest tag. Then, I run: aws ecs update-service --cluster myCluster --service myService --task-definition myTaskDefinition --force-new-deployment and… Nothing happens! I would expect tasks go down and come up. But not. What could I be missing or net seeing?

Comment: @Peter No problem. Can you inspect the events tab in Service console in ECS. This usually has some more info on what's happening.

Comment: Thanks, @Marcin. Weird issue. It worked but after 2 hours (that's why I was not seeing the changes, nor messages in the events tab). However, today is working and takes 10/15 minutes. And... Nothing changed!

Comment: @Peter The one thing that could be also tried is to use image digest in task definition instead of `latest`. Example in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_image). I heard about cases where `latest` was not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

First thing as mentioned by @Marcin, in such deployed where `--force-new-deployment` is not specified and no change in the task definition revision the deployment will ignore by ECS agent.

The second thing that you are seeing replica after deployment is `minimumHealthyPercent and maximumPercent` as the service scheduler uses these parameters to determine the deployment strategy.

**minimumHealthyPercent**

> If `minimumHealthyPercent` is below 100%, the scheduler can ignore
> desiredCount temporarily during a deployment. **For example, if
> desiredCount is four tasks, a minimum of 50% allows the scheduler to
> stop two existing tasks before starting two new tasks.** Tasks for
> services that do not use a load balancer are considered healthy if
> they are in the RUNNING state. Tasks for services that use a load
> balancer are considered healthy if they are in the RUNNING state and
> the container instance they are hosted on is reported as healthy by
> the load balancer.

**maximumPercent**

The `maximumPercent` parameter represents an upper limit on the number of running tasks during a deployment, which enables you to define the deployment batch size. **For example, if `desiredCount` is four tasks, a maximum of 200% starts four new tasks before stopping the four older tasks (provided that the cluster resources required to do this are available)**.

[Modifies the parameters of a service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html)

So setting `minimumHealthyPercent` is to `50%` the scheduled will stop one exiting task before starting one new task. setting it will `0` then you may see the bad gateway from LB as it will stop both exiting tasks before starting two one.

If you still not able to control  the flow then pass the `--desired-count`

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster test --service test --task-definition test --force-new-deployment --desired-count 2
```